# How to stop an activity started with implicit intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL etc) from a service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I would like to stop an activity started with implicit intent(using Intent.ACTIN_CALL etc). Is there a way to do this?
Also when we use "startActivity()" function of Context(abstract class), how does it actually start it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot stop an activity.

To answer your second question, when you call `startActivity()` the `Intent` that you pass as a parameter is given to the Android framework. The framework performs the appropriate `Intent resolution` using the contents of the `Intent` to determine which activity to actually start. Then, depending on the activity that needs to be started, it may need to create a new OS process, instantiate the `Application` object for that application and finally instantiate the activity object and call `onCreate()` on it. However, there are other things that may or may not happen during this process, depending on the state of the task that contains the activity, the `Intent` flags used, the `launchMode` of the activity as defined in the manifest, etc.

Comment: Thanks. How about programmatically pressing END button of a phone call? Do you have any idea doing this?